# What features does BlueZ support?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm new to bluetooth programming and can't seem to figure out the exact features that are supported by BlueZ.

Is there a way to get these working on Ubuntu:

- audio streaming over bluetooth, AVRCP
- browse audio files on a phone
- phone book access (PBAP)
- browse messages
- answering phone calls

In my Ubuntu 14.04 I see only `Send a file` option (which also fails for some reason).
Are there any bluez tools to achieve the above? Or are they at least supported by the API?

Comment: The openobex has docs on how to use the API. At least the PBAP DBUS function interface API documentation can be found in the doc "client-api.txt".

Comment: I can confirm to you that at least browsing files on a phone over bluetooth works on BlueZ 4 (haven't tested BlueZ 5).